# How to change the bluetooth headset button click functionality?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have made a broadcast receiver with the below code.

```
public class MediaButtonsIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public MediaButtonsIntentReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String intentAction= intent.getAction();
        if(!Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intentAction)){
            return;
        }
        KeyEvent event=(KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
        if(event==null){
            return;
        }
        int action = event.getAction();
        if(action==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            int keycode = event.getKeyCode();
            if(keycode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
                Toast.makeText(context, "hiii bro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(keycode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
                Toast.makeText(context, "hiii bro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(keycode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT){
                Toast.makeText(context, "hiii bro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(keycode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS){
                Toast.makeText(context, "hiii bro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        abortBroadcast();
    }
}
```

In my main activity I have registered the broadcast receiver with 10000 priority.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        MediaButtonsIntentReceiver r = new MediaButtonsIntentReceiver();
        filter.setPriority(10000);
        registerReceiver(r, filter);
    }
}
```

In manifest

```
    <receiver
android:name=".MediaButtonsIntentReceiver">
<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON">
</action> </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
```

I don't know why it's not working. I want to make it run even when my mobile screen is locked.

Comment: I know this is a downvote answer but you need a ForegroundService